# Collecting return code and stdout string from running SAS program in Linux KornShell script

Tags: linux, shell, sas, stdout, ksh

Some developers and I are using KornShell (ksh) to run SAS programs in a Linux environment. The script invokes a SAS command line and I wish to collect the stdout from the SAS execution (a string defined and written by SAS) as well as the Linux return code (0/1).

#### My Code (collects stdout into envar, but return_code is always 0 because the envar assignment was successful):

```
envar=$(./sas XXXX/filename.sas -log $LOG_FILE)

return_code=$?
```

Is there a way to collect both the return code and the std out without having to submit this command twice?

Comment: Your hypothesis is incorrect: `a=$( echo foo; false); echo $?` prints 1

Comment: Any particular reason you can't have SAS write to a file rather than to STDOUT?

Comment: William Pursell - you are correct. I appear to be picking up the SAS execution code. When the executed SAS program has a bug, it starts returning different error codes.

Joe - SAS actually spits out a very detailed log file. I need the results of stdout and the return code both in variables as these represent different reasons for errors and thus different responsible parties for contact via ksh email.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

SAS does not write anything to STDOUT when it is run as a non-interactive process.  The log file contains the record of statements executed and step statistics; "printed" output (such as from `proc print`) is written to a "listing" file.  By default, that file will be created using the name of your source file appended with ".lst" (in your case, **filename.lst**).

You are providing a file to accept the log output using the `-log` system option.  The related option to define the listing file is the `-print` option.  Of course, if the program does not create any listing output, such an option isn't needed.

And as you've discovered, the value returned by `$?` is the execution return code from SAS.  Any non-zero value will indicate some sort of error occurred during program execution.

If you want to influence the return code, you can use the `ABORT` data step statement in your SAS program.  That will immediately halt the SAS program as set the return code to something meaningful to you.  For example, suppose you want to terminate further processing if a particular `PROC SQL` step fails:

```
data _null_;
   rc = symgetn('SQLRC');
   put rc=;
   if rc > 0 then ABORT RETURN 10;
run;
```

This would set the return code to `10` and you could use your outer script to send an email to the appropriate person.  Such a custom return code value must be greater than 6 and less than 976; other values are reserved for SAS.  [Here is the SAS doc link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/63053/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0cndzg0o5pkcin1831y552h89hf.htm).

Comment: SAS can write to STDOUT if you use the -stdio option. see http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#unx-sysopt-stdio.htm